# Need help making navbar change from a transparent background to a solid background on scroll

Tags: jquery, html, css, scroll, navbar

When I try to use js it does not change after 50px it just stays the same transparency..

here's my code: 
https://codepen.io/greenmistweb/pen/WNeppeE

I've tried to find youtube tutorials but none of them want to work

```
$(function() {
   $(window).scroll(function () {
      if ($(this).scrollTop() > 50) {
         $(‘topnav’).addClass(‘changeColor’)
      }
      if ($(this).scrollTop() < 50) {
         $(‘topnav’).removeClass(‘changeColor’)
      }
   });
});
```

Thought this would make it go to the .changeColor in CSS after scrolling past 50px but it doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tweeked your code slightly and you seems to have a couple of issues going for you:

1. You don't have jquery imported
2. Your javascript code was probably copied and pasted which was causing an error with `'`;
3. You were trying to reference 'topnav' instead of using the **class name** `.topnav`;

I had adjusted your position check to use your `about-me` div as reference when changing the colour as using a static `50px` value might bring up some problems in the future;

```js
$(function() {
   var aboutMePosition = $('.about-me').position().top;
   $(window).scroll(function () {
     var currentPosition = $(this).scrollTop();
      if (currentPosition >= aboutMePosition) {
         $('.topnav').addClass('changeColor')
      } else {
         $('.topnav').removeClass('changeColor')
      }
   });
});
```

```css
@font-face {
 font-family: 'Poiret One';
 font-style: normal;
 src: url(Fonts/PoiretOne-Regular.ttf);
}

@font-face {
 font-family: 'Darker Grotesque';
 src: url(Fonts/DarkerGrotesque-Light.ttf);
}

@font-face {
 font-family: 'Pathway Gothic';
 src: url(Fonts/PathwayGothicOne-Regular.ttf);
}


/* Add a black background color to the top navigation */
.topnav {
  background-color: transparent;
  overflow: hidden;
 position: fixed;
 top: 0;
 width: 100%;
 z-index: 1000;
 font-family: 'Darker Grotesque', sans-serif;
 transition: .5s;
}

/* Style the links inside the navigation bar */
.topnav a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

/* Change the color of links on hover */
.topnav a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

/* Add an active class to highlight the current page */
.topnav a.active {
  color: white;
}

/* Hide the link that should open and close the topnav on small screens */
.topnav .icon {
  display: none;
}

/* When the screen is less than 600 pixels wide, hide all links, except for the first one ("Home"). Show the link that contains should open and close the topnav (.icon) */
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav a:not(:first-child) {display: none;}
  .topnav a.icon {
    float: right;
    display: block;
  }
}

/* The "responsive" class is added to the topnav with JavaScript when the user clicks on the icon. This class makes the topnav look good on small screens (display the links vertically instead of horizontally) */
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav.responsive {position: relative;}
  .topnav.responsive a.icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  .topnav.responsive a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
}

.card {
 background: white;
 margin-bottom: 2em;
}

.card a {
 color: black;
 text-decoration: none;
}

.card a:hover {
 box-shadow: 3px 3px 8px hsl(0, 0%, 80%);
}

.card-content {
 padding: 1.4em;
}

.card-content h2 {
 margin-top: 0;
 margin-bottom: .5em;
 font-weight: bold;
}

.card-content p {
 font-size: 80%;
}

/* Flexbox stuff */

.cards {
   display: flex;
   flex-wrap: wrap;
   justify-content: space-between;
}

.card {
 flex: 0 1 24%;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .services {
    margin:20px
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width:600px) {
  .service-list {
    flex: 0 1 50%;
  }
}


body, html {
    height: 100%;
}

/* The hero image */
.hero-image {
  /* Use "linear-gradient" to add a darken background effect to the image (photographer.jpg). This will make the text easier to read */
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)), url("first-img.jpg");

  /* Set a specific height */
  height: 650px;

  /* Position and center the image to scale nicely on all screens */
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
 margin: -10px;
}

/* Place text in the middle of the image */
.hero-text {
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  color: white;
 font-family: 'Poiret One';
}

.who-i-am {
 display: flex;
 width: 600px;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
}

.description {
 flex: 1;
 margin: 50px;
}

.about-me {
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: row;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.centered-link a {
  float: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.serv-desc {
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: row;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.service {
 flex-basis: 100%;
 text-align: center;
 margin: 30px;
 font-family: 'Pathway Gothic';
}

@media screen and (min-width:600px) {
 .service {
  flex: 1;
 }
}

h2 {
 text-align: center;
 font-family: 'Pathway Gothic';
}

.changeColor {
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="dwaynes_logo_no_words.png">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>greenMist Web Solutions</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

    <div class="topnav">
      <a href="#home" class="active">Home</a>
      <a href="#news">News</a>
      <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
      <a href="#about">About</a>
      <div class="centered-link">
        <a class="brand" href="#home">greenMist Web Solutions</a>
      </div>
      <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">
        <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
      </a>
    </div>

    <div class="hero-image">
      <div class="hero-text">
        <h1>I am Dwayne Rill, Jr.</h1>
        <p></p>
        <button></button>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="about-me">
      <div class="who-i-am">
        <h1>About Me</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="description">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor
        incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation
        ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit
        in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat
        non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        <br>
        <br>
        This is some more info
        <br>
        <br>
        and some more
        <br>
        <br>
        and another one!
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="services">
      <h2>Services</h2>
      <div class="serv-desc">
        <div class="service">
          <div id="frontEnd">
          <h3>Front-End Development</h3>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor
            incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud
            exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
            dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
            Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt
            mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="service">
          <div id="responive">
          <h3>Responsive Development</h3>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor
            incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud
            exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
            dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
            Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt
            mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="service">
          <div id="migration">
          <h3>Host Migration</h3>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor
            incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud
            exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
            dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
            Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt
            mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="pricing options">
      words
    </div>

    <div class="contact me">
      words
    </div>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: How is this answer any different than the one I posted?

Comment: Thanks! I'm very very very much a beginner when it comes to javascript. I'm trying to teach myself, I couldn't work it out so I copied and pasted a bit of code to try to work out what I was doing wrong, but then it didn't work either. Thanks for helping me out!

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple things going on with your code:

1. Your single quotes are fancy quotes. They need to be replaced with normal single quotes.
2. `$('topnav')` should be `$('.topnav')` - notice that you weren't selecting an element with the class `topnav`. Your code was looking for an element with that name.
3. You didn't include jQuery anywhere, so this `$` means nothing to the code.

Here's a working example:

```js
(function($) {
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 50) {
      $('.topnav').addClass('changeColor')
    }
    if ($(this).scrollTop() < 50) {
      $('.topnav').removeClass('changeColor')
    }
  });
})(jQuery);
```

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Poiret One';
  font-style: normal;
  src: url(Fonts/PoiretOne-Regular.ttf);
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Darker Grotesque';
  src: url(Fonts/DarkerGrotesque-Light.ttf);
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Pathway Gothic';
  src: url(Fonts/PathwayGothicOne-Regular.ttf);
}


/* Add a black background color to the top navigation */

.topnav {
  background-color: transparent;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1000;
  font-family: 'Darker Grotesque', sans-serif;
  transition: .5s;
}


/* Style the links inside the navigation bar */

.topnav a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}


/* Change the color of links on hover */

.topnav a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}


/* Add an active class to highlight the current page */

.topnav a.active {
  color: white;
}


/* Hide the link that should open and close the topnav on small screens */

.topnav .icon {
  display: none;
}


/* When the screen is less than 600 pixels wide, hide all links, except for the first one ("Home"). Show the link that contains should open and close the topnav (.icon) */

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav a:not(:first-child) {
    display: none;
  }
  .topnav a.icon {
    float: right;
    display: block;
  }
}


/* The "responsive" class is added to the topnav with JavaScript when the user clicks on the icon. This class makes the topnav look good on small screens (display the links vertically instead of horizontally) */

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav.responsive {
    position: relative;
  }
  .topnav.responsive a.icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  .topnav.responsive a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
}

.card {
  background: white;
  margin-bottom: 2em;
}

.card a {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.card a:hover {
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 8px hsl(0, 0%, 80%);
}

.card-content {
  padding: 1.4em;
}

.card-content h2 {
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: .5em;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.card-content p {
  font-size: 80%;
}


/* Flexbox stuff */

.cards {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.card {
  flex: 0 1 24%;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .services {
    margin: 20px
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width:600px) {
  .service-list {
    flex: 0 1 50%;
  }
}

body,
html {
  height: 100%;
}


/* The hero image */

.hero-image {
  /* Use "linear-gradient" to add a darken background effect to the image (photographer.jpg). This will make the text easier to read */
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)), url("first-img.jpg");
  /* Set a specific height */
  height: 650px;
  /* Position and center the image to scale nicely on all screens */
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
  margin: -10px;
}


/* Place text in the middle of the image */

.hero-text {
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Poiret One';
}

.who-i-am {
  display: flex;
  width: 600px;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.description {
  flex: 1;
  margin: 50px;
}

.about-me {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.centered-link a {
  float: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.serv-desc {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.service {
  flex-basis: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 30px;
  font-family: 'Pathway Gothic';
}

@media screen and (min-width:600px) {
  .service {
    flex: 1;
  }
}

h2 {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Pathway Gothic';
}

.changeColor {
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="dwaynes_logo_no_words.png">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <title>greenMist Web Solutions</title>
</head>

<body>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

  <div class="topnav">
    <a href="#home" class="active">Home</a>
    <a href="#news">News</a>
    <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
    <a href="#about">About</a>
    <div class="centered-link">
      <a class="brand" href="#home">greenMist Web Solutions</a>
    </div>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">
      <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
    </a>
  </div>

  <div class="hero-image">
    <div class="hero-text">
      <h1>I am Dwayne Rill, Jr.</h1>
      <p></p>
      <button></button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="about-me">
    <div class="who-i-am">
      <h1>About Me</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="description">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
      in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
      <br>
      <br> This is some more info
      <br>
      <br> and some more
      <br>
      <br> and another one!
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="services">
    <h2>Services</h2>
    <div class="serv-desc">
      <div class="service">
        <div id="frontEnd">
          <h3>Front-End Development</h3>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute
            irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="service">
        <div id="responive">
          <h3>Responsive Development</h3>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute
            irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="service">
        <div id="migration">
          <h3>Host Migration</h3>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute
            irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="pricing options">
    words
  </div>

  <div class="contact me">
    words
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Here's a codepen to play with:
https://codepen.io/chrislafrombois/pen/aboJJdx

Comment: Thanks to you as well! I appreciate you taking the time out to answer the question too!